# The value is not valid for double/decimal

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, jquery-globalize

[image]
[image]

Hello, I've been trying to get this to work for ages now and I've ran out of options. No matter what I try, the value for a double/decimal is always invalid according to the Jquery validator. This is a list of what I tried:

- Set culture in web.config
- Set culture in CurrentThread
- Change type from Decimal to Double
- Change input type from Number to Text
- Use globalize.js
- Use a custom regex fix found on here
- Use a DecimalBinder found on here

Nothing, absolutely nothing fixes this error. I'd greatly appreciate if somebody could point out what I was doing wrong here.

Comment: It looks like you gave comma (,) in 55,95. Was that expected?

Comment: The number input automatically changes it to a comma, eventhough in the validation it says a dot (.)

Comment: Please NEVER use a picture in place of posting the actual code.  It breaks the search index and nobody can cut and paste.

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayFormat.DataFormatString` [uses .NET's predefined formatting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings). In particular, the `.` (dot/period) is always interpreted to mean "the decimal point of the **current culture**", which in your case is `,`, or comma.

If you want a literal dot separating the whole and fractional parts of the number, you need to escape it:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:0\.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```